# Initialize a GridView with an initially unused SelectParameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Is there a way to define SessionParamters in the SelectParameters of a DataSource that aren't called in the SelectCommand?

I want the parameter to be defined so it can be used later, after initial page generation, but when it's not used in the SelectCommand the DataSource doesn't seem to work - the GridView which calls it appears empty, yet generates fine when the unused Parameters are excluded.

For example, the following definition will fill the GridView successfully:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE @UsedParameter='Green'">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="UsedParameter" SessionField="Parameter1" />              
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Whereas the following would not fill the GridView:

```
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE @UsedParameter='Green'">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="UsedParameter" SessionField="Parameter1" />  
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="UnUsedParameter2" SessionField="Parameter2" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is interesting... I think I've seen that problem before when I forgot to remove a parameter.  Since you are likely going to change the select command later to use the other parameter, why don't you just add the parameter at that time?

**VB**

```
    Dim p As New SessionParameter("UnUsedParameter2", "Parameter2")
    DataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(p)
```

**C#**

```
     SessionParameter p = new SessionParameter("UnUsedParameter2", "Parameter2")
     DataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(p);
```

Comment: This worked a charm. Thanks! I added C# code to your answer for the sake of completeness.